# Multiple API Calls in a Class

Tags: php, arrays, api, scope

I am trying to make multiple API requests and I have to make the request in different functions that are within a class like so:

```
class exampleClass
{    
  function callFunction1 () {
    // stuff that makes a call
    return $json;
  }

  function printStuffOut() {
    $jsonStuff = $this->callFunction1();
    $$jsonStuff->{'result'}[0]->{'fieldName'};
  }

  function printStuffOut2() {
    $jsonStuff = $this->callFunction1();
    $jsonStuff->{'result'}[0]->{'fieldName'};
  }
}
```

Am I making two separate API calls?

If I am, is there a way to store that API call information say in an array then use that array in all the other functions in my class?

Answer (score 3):

Answer to first question: Yes you are, each time the method is called it executes all its definition again.

Answer to second question: Yes there is, so called member properties. You can read up about them in the PHP manual here: [PHP Manual: Properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Answer (score 1):

You are making two API calls, but you don't have to.

You can put the contents of a call into a member variable in the class with a default value of `NULL`, and if you want, you can check if that member variable is `NULL` before making an API call. For example;

```
class exampleClass
{
    private $api_json = NULL;

    private function call_api()
    {
        if(is_null($this->api_json))
        {
            $json = // result of api call;
            $this->api_json = $json;
        }

        return $this->api_json;
    }

    public function printStuffOut() {
        $jsonStuff = $this->call_api();
        $jsonStuff->{'result'}[0]->{'fieldName'};
    }

    public function printStuffOut2() {
        $jsonStuff = $this->call_api();
        $jsonStuff->{'result'}[0]->{'fieldName'};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following class to achieve multiple API simultaneously/instantly/at once.

[Click here](https://github.com/delickate/codeigniter) to get a class.

How to use it?

Step 1: Get object.

```
//SANI: GET DATA    
$obj = new multiapi();
```

Step 2: Make a multiple GET Requests.

```
$obj->data = array(YOUR_URL_1,YOUR_URL_2, OUR_URL_3);
$result = $obj->get_process_requests();
print_r($result);
```

Step 3: Make a multiple HTTP POST Requests.

```
//SANI: Request with params only
$obj->data[0]['url']             = 'YOUR_URL_ONE';
$obj->data[0]['post']                = array();
$obj->data[0]['post']['param_1']     = 'param_value_1';
$obj->data[0]['post']['param_2']     = 'param_value_2';
```